# How to debug in Firebug when code is in separate JS file?

Tags: javascript, firebug

I am starting out with Firebug.

I have a JS file that has some JQuery in it.

how do I debug that code when the HTML page rendered
does not have any javascript just ref
to my file.

thanks
Malcolm

Answer (score 6):

If you go to the script tab there'll be a little drop down box that will you let you select any scripts linked to in the page. Won't help you much if they're minified though...

Answer (score 4):

Open Firebug. Click on "Script" then choose your external JS-File from the dropdown menu.

Comment: I did no scripts there yet I have a few linked, help. Any chance you teaching me how to use it?????

Comment: I think this new version is buggy, I am going back to older version

Comment: How did you link the JavaScript-files from the HTML-page? Can you post some code?

Comment: you need to enable the "script" by going to "Net" section in firebug

Comment: Ok I discovered that my path to the JS file was wrong and now fixed it and Firebug sees it Net tab. BUT the Script menu still does not have any script file????

Answer (score 3):

You can add "debugger;" string before the line which you want to debug.

This will invoke Firebug's JS debugger.

Answer (score 2):

In the new firebug you need to click on the file list to get access to external js files. It is no longer in the "Script Tab". Once you've changed to the js file you want to set the breakpoint in you just need to click the line number on the left and reload the page.

[alt text http://rival-studios.com/Portals/0/so-firebug.gif](http://rival-studios.com/Portals/0/so-firebug.gif)

Comment: Where do you mean "file list"?? This is set a breakpoint in a js file right.

Comment: Sorry I didn't really explain it right in my first response. I've made it more concise now.

Comment: Note: When I was new to Firebug took me some time to find the "file list" too. Just updating the answer in case any other newbie gets stuck on it. 1) In the "Script" tab there is a drop down list for files. Normally if the current html page is "index.html" say, then you should see a [index.html^] in firebug.  
2) You may need to scroll up/down the file list with mouse to select a particular file. The script window then shows the code for that file.  
3) Now you can set a breakpoint in that file.

Comment: Is there an update for this answer for Firebug 2.0.18?  Firefox's Integrated debugger shows me a big list of .js files - but Firebug never shows anything - a message tells me there is no JavaScript on the current page ( I knew that!) - and the <script> tab  only shows options to break on exceptions or ignore them.  (The application is a large backbone application)